# Mongo Update of Array Query using Upsert

Tags: python, mongodb

Given

1. menuItems is a list ['foo', 'bar', 'fooz', 'ball'] and
2. menudb collection has 3 records: 'foo', 'bar', 'fooz'

When I run

```
menudb.update({"_id" : {"$in": menuItems}}, {"$addToSet": {"staleCount": 100}}, upsert=True)
```

Instead of creating a new record called 'ball', it creates a new record called 'ObjectId("57d730777bc6a465c9124111")'.

Is there a way to make the newly created record's '_id' to be that from the list?

=Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can remove upsert if you do not want new item in the menudb collection. I seems like your id is objectId instead of string.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

you can verify if the _id foo exits in collection 
menudb.update({"_id" : "foo"}, {"$addToSet": {"staleCount": 100})

Comment: I do want the new item to be created, but with the '_id' as 'ball'

Comment: run following to verify if the _id is correct in the collection. db. menudb.find()   The output will show the _id as string or object...e.g.
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773e26e27819b2bf0479460"), "Name" : "a", "Email" : "a@a.com
" }
>